# How to select data from a queryset and group by counts for a specific date

Tags: python, django, django-queryset, django-aggregation

When I query my database I get the same entry three times with three different counts. In the result list I would like to get just one entry showing the sum of these counts.

What I would like to display is the total for a specific period.

In my query I enter the dates (from - until), a metric_type, a data_type and a year of publication.

For instance I on the website when I enter

```
from 201903 until 201905
```

I retrieve three titles that have been accessed in this period as well as how many times they have been accessed.

```
Title, Publisher,    DOI,   data_type,YOP,[some other stuff] Counts

Title A  publisherA   1234    Article, 2006, [some_other_stuff], 3
Title A  publisherA   1234    Article, 2006, [some_other_stuff], 5
Title A  publisherA   1234    Article, 2006, [some_other_stuff], 3
```

What I would need is something like

```
Title, publisher, DOI,   data_type, YOP,  [some_other_stuff],  Total period

Title A, publisherA 1234   Article, 2006,   [some_other_stuff],    11
```

In views.py I have the following code:

```
    q_report = Q()


        var0 = self.request.GET.get("period1", "")
        var1 = self.request.GET.get("period2", "")
        var2 = self.request.GET.get("metric_type", "")
        var3 = self.request.GET.get("data_type", "")
        var4 = self.request.GET.get("YOP", "")



        if var0:
            q_report = q_report & (Q(month__gte=var0) & Q(month__lte=var1) )
            #q_report_count = q_report_count & (Count(month__gte=var0) & Count(month__lte=var1) )
        if var2:
            q_report = q_report & (Q(metric_type=var2))
            #q_report_count = q_report_count & (Q(metric_type=var2))
        if var3:
             q_report = q_report & (Q(data_type=var3))
        if var4:
             q_report = q_report & (Q(YOP=var4))
```

If I use

```
qs = self.model.objects.filter(q_report).select_related()
```

I will get back the three entries

The result is

```
<QuerySet [<Model: Title A>, <Model: Title A>, <Model: Title A>]>
```

I can easily calculate the total by using

```
total = self.model.objects.aggregate(total=Sum('counts', filter=q_report))
```

The result is

```
{total : 11.0}
```

But ideally I need to get the other values as well

Right now, I cannot see how I can get the two together, i.e. something like

```
<QuerySet [<Model: {'title':Title A, 'total':11}>, Model: {'title':Title B, 'total':7}>]
```

I don't even know whether this is possible or desired. But I need to return the queryset and the total.

Can anyone help? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is in essence a modeling problem. Instead of defining a model like:

```
# modeling with data duplication

class SomeModel(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    publisher = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    doi = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    publication_type = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    year = models.IntegerField()
    date = models.DateField()
    counts = models.IntegerField()
```

You should make a model like `Publication`, and link the `SomeModel` to that `Publication`, like:

```
# modeling without data duplication

class Publication(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    publisher = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    doi = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    publication_type = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    year = models.IntegerField()

class PublicationSale(models.Model):
    publication = models.ForeignKey(Publication, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date = models.DateField()
    counts = models.IntegerField()
```

This will reduce the database size, will make it less likely that your database has inconsistencies (like if you change the year of a publication that some records are not updated properly), and it might make the database faster for some queries.

In that case you can query like:

```
from django.db.models import Sum

Publication.objects.annotate(
    total=Sum('publication_sale__counts')
)
```

You then retrieve a `QuerySet` with `Publication` objects that carry an extra attribute `.totals` that is the sum of the `counts` of the *related* `PublicationSale` objects.

If you do not do this remodeling, you can work with:

```
from django.db.models import Sum

qs = self.model.objects.filter(q_report).values(
    'title', 'publisher', 'doi', 'publication_type', 'year'
).annotate(
    total=Sum('counts')
).order_by(
    'title', 'publisher', 'doi', 'publication_type', 'year'
)
```

which then results in a `QuerySet` of dictionaries:

```
<QuerySet [
    {'title': 'Title A', 'publisher': 'pubA', ..., 'total': 11},
    {'title': 'Title B', 'publisher': 'pubA', ..., 'total': 7},
    {'title': 'Title A', 'publisher': 'pubB', ..., 'total': 3},
]>
```

But as you can see the query does not yield models, and it is a bit "unstable" in the sense that each time you add extra data of your "functionally related entity", you will need to update the query.

Comment: Thank you, that's useful, but I really need a queryset that looks like this:

```
<QuerySet [<model:
    {'title': 'Title A', 'total': 11}>,<model:{'title':'Title B', 'total':7}>, <model:{'title':'Title B', 'total':3}>]

    {'title': 'Title B', 'total': 7},
    {'title': 'Title C', 'total': 3},
]>
```
If the model name is not in there, only the title will be displayed, not everything else. If I leave out  .values('title'), I get the same query set as before...

Comment: @PyBear: but since these are (if I understood it correctly), different models, what model do you want to return?

Comment: Oh no, it's the same model, actually. The things is, if I use your solution in my result list only the title is displayed and none of the other meta data which are supposed to be there, like publisher, DOI, ISBN, data_type etc. Sorry - I simplified to much above, so this part didn't get across correctly. I'll try and edit the original question.

Comment: @Py_Bear: well if these are separate models, you can annotate like `MyModel.filter(..).annotate(total=Sum('counts'))`, then each `MyModel` will have an attribute `.total`, but this will then always be a multiple of the `Counts` of that record evidently.

Comment: @BearBrown: because otherwise the query will not perform a `GROUP BY title`.

Comment: @Py_Bear: this really looks like "bad modeling": your rows repeat all kinds of data, and therefore grouping is hard. You should make a different model, like `Publication`, and use a `ForeignKey` to avoid duplication, in that case, annotating is simple, and the database will typically be smaller and faster.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your query by

```
self.model.objects.filter(q_report).annotate(total=Sum('counts')).values('title','total')
```

Where total would be the field you want to sum

Comment: Thanks but this results in an empty queryset.

Comment: Oh,but on my codes it works always.You can try this one also

 self.model.objects.filter(q_report).values('title','publisher').aggregate(total=Sum('counts')).get('total')